# Google App Engine JDO makePersistent latency

Tags: google-app-engine, persistence, jdo, latency

I have a problem with the Google App Engine JDO implementation that I cannot figure out. The documentation (http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html) states "The call to makePersistent() is synchronous, and doesn't return until the object is saved and indexes are updated." but my experience differs.

I want to save (makePersistent) an object into the datastore. When the save is complete I want to be able to fetch it (Query execute) from the datastore immediately. I know that I don't have to fetch it (because I already have the object in memory) but the point is that I want the next request to be able to retrieve the data from the datastore. That is not working with the current implementation if the second request is fast enough.

One strange thing I've noticed is that if I'm trying to fetch the object from the datastore a couple of times in a loop (code below) the object is returned really quick (usually < 10ms). But if I skip the loop and instead run Thread.sleep(..) for 5000 ms between makePersistent and query execute it's not certain that the object is found. None of these solutions are what I want. I want to be able to fetch the data right away without a sleep or loop in between.

The code and the result from accessing the DataStoreTestServlet below is as you can see including the loop that is "waiting" for the data to be found. Again, I don't want the loop.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? I guess it has to be something. This implementation doesn't feel right to me :).

I'm using appengine-java-sdk-1.6.0. This is an issue both locally (development server) and when deployed on the Google servers.

Here's the result from accessing the servlet.

```
Created users:
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966416] took 18ms, 2 loop(s)
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966438] took 15ms, 6 loop(s)
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966456] took 2ms, 1 loop(s)
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966460] took 10ms, 5 loop(s)
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966472] took 0ms, 1 loop(s)
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966472] took 0ms, 1 loop(s)
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966472] took 16ms, 1 loop(s)
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966488] took 0ms, 2 loop(s)
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966488] took 0ms, 1 loop(s)
User [password=password, userName=user1321190966488] took 16ms, 1 loop(s)
```

The code and configuration.

jdoconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">
<persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
<property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
<property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
<property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
<property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
<property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="STRONG" />
</persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

PMF.java

```
import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;

public final class PMF {
    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private PMF() {
    }

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }
}
```

User.java

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private String userName;

    @Persistent
    private String password;

    public User(String userName, String password) {
        super();
        this.setUserName(userName);
        this.setPassword(password);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "User [password=" + password + ", userName=" + userName + "]";
    }
}
```

DataStoreTestServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.Query;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DataStoreTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("Created users:\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String uniqueName = "user" + System.currentTimeMillis();
            User user = new User(uniqueName, "password");
            save(user);

            User userFromDS = null;
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long loop = 0;
            while (userFromDS == null) {
                userFromDS = get(uniqueName);
                loop++;
                if (userFromDS != null) {
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    sb.append(userFromDS.toString() + " took " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms, " + loop + " loop(s)\n");
                }
            }
        }
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println(sb.toString());
    }

    public Object save(Object obj) {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Object savedObject = null;
        try {
            savedObject = pm.makePersistent(obj);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
        return savedObject;
    }

    public User get(String userName) {
        User user = null;
        List<User> users = null;
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class);
        query.setFilter("userName == nameParam");
        query.declareParameters("String nameParam");
        try {
            users = (List<User>) query.execute(userName);
            if (users != null && users.size() > 0) {
                user = users.get(0);
            }
        } finally {
            query.closeAll();
            pm.close();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this in your jdoconfig.xml:

```
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="STRONG" />
```

To increase performance; the app engine datastore is "eventually consistent".  This means that when you make new objects or alter existing ones, it doesn't show up right away; allowing for performance gains in lookup times.  The opposite of this is "STRONG" consistency, meaning every request is made using the most recent data in the datastore.

Now, according to the [app engine documentation for this](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview.html) STRONG consistent is the default, and you have to explicitly set eventual consistency.  But, from what I've observed, you have to set STRONG consistency and EVENTUAL is the default (bug maybe?).  So try adding the above to your jdoconfig xml and if you observe the same thing I did then I'll probably open a bug against app engine, assuming one hasn't been opened already for this issue.

The one thing you're going to have to keep in mind is that if you set STRONG consistency, you're going to take a performance hit.  I only set it because there were parts of my interface that were getting messed up because I would build a piece of it with not so fresh data, and during the same request another piece would get built with fresh data; making my interface inconsistent.  This might be a broad approach to fixing the problem; but it works :).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the property, but there is no change. I still have to loop a couple of times trying to fetch the data before it succeeds :(. Very strange.

Comment: When I first posted this answer, I accidentally posted `<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="EVENTUAL" />`  but it should be `<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="STRONG" />`  (NOTE `STRONG` as opposed to `EVENTUAL`).  This is my fault; but are you sure you tried with the `STRONG` setting?

Comment: Hehe, yes I tried it with the STRONG setting. I also tried the following on my query.        query.addExtension("datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency", "STRONG");
Still the same issue.

Comment: My only other guess is that because you're doing this all on the same request that the persistence manager is doing something under the hood (ie - doesn't actually persist until the http request is completed via some internal app engine servlet filter). So, maybe try on your actual application; or rewrite your test servlet to save once, and then redirect to itself and check to see if your item persisted OK.

Comment: Thanks for the hint that it could be based on the request. It seems to  be. When deployed at the Google servers <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="STRONG" /> works. It still doesn't work locally, but that's not a big problem.
Like you said it seems to be a bug that the property has to be set to STRONG. The documentation states that it should be STRONG by default, but it's clearly not.

Comment: Can track here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6326&thanks=6326&ts=1321204205

Comment: just out of interest I have just run into this problem myself in my live environment. Customers are saving appointments into the database, then opening them up again, finding the data is wrong, correcting it then writing it back again, and then finding combinations of the two updates apparently randomly mixed up in the database. Im now writing every database update into an audit trail record, and its amazing whats actually going on inside the database, its REALLY inconsistent and apparently unpredictable!

Comment: Further to my comment above i read the following link thoroughly, and i completely understand it, but what i cant work out is how to know when all the milestones have been complete?! IE, when makePersistent is actually completed. Interestingly I am also reproducing this problem on my local machine, and given there is only one database, I'm really surprised that it happens here too!

Comment: johnvdenley - I wrote this two years ago.  If you're still running into this problem I'd recommend looking into alternatives or switching to a SQL db.  Also, possibly consider opening a question on SO and posting your code for your update.  I had a few app engine questions when I was actually trying it and it seems as though there are app engine employees actively monitoring the app engine tag on StackOverflow.  Heroku and AWS Elastic beanstalk are good alternatives to investigate.